# Unsubscribe my own video in opentok

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

Hi I am using opentok.

When I say

```
publisher = OT.initPublisher(); 

session.publish(publisher);
```

My own video is visible to myself. I want to see only other participants video but not my own. I want my video to be visible to everyone else in the session except me.

How to make this possible.

And can I make other people video to full-screen?

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

var publisher = OT.initPublisher('myPublisherDiv', {display: 'none'});

session.publish(publisher);

Or you can explicitly check on the video using firebug or chrome dev tool and see if it has an existing class or id, then you can just add in a display none on the class ex.

.video-class{
    display:none
}